# How to read fingerprint of known hosts key?

Tags: ssh

Someone is trying to login to a host:

```
❯ sudo sshuttle --dns -r root@XXXX 0/0 
The authenticity of host 'XXXX (XXXX)' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:YYYY.
```

They previously connected to this host:

```
❯ cat ~/.ssh/known_hosts | grep XXXX
199.195.254.120 ssh-ed25519 ZZZZ
```

How to compare this fingerprint to this public key?